# Redirecting to parent state on tab click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic application that has 4 tabs menu and one of tabs is actual menu page that has some links of it's own, so quick snippet:

```
.state('menu', {
    url: '/menu',
    params: {user: null},
    views: {
      'tab-menu': {
        templateUrl: 'menu.html',
        controller: 'menuCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
.state('user-profile', {
    url: '/menu/profile',
    params: {user: null},
    views: {
      'tab-menu': {
        templateUrl: 'user-profile.html',
        controller: 'menuCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

So when user taps "Menu" Ionic tab, and then taps on profile page, everything works fine. Then user clicks "Home" tab and that also works fine. But after that, when user taps on "Menu" tab again it will go to profile page, and not to actual Menu page.

How do I make it go to menu page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem as follows:

Tabs have `ui-sref` property:

```
ui-sref="main.live.tabs.ranking"
```

And this is causing the problem with redirection. Instead, just create controller with method

```
$scope.goToState = function () {
    $state.go('state');
}
```

And modify tab by removing `ui-sref` and replacing it with

```
ng-click="goToState()"
```